# debmake FileNotFound error

Tags: debian

I am having a issue with debmake now.
I followed https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debmake-doc/ch04.en.html#packaging-tarball chapter 4 to test debmake

The project's directory structure looks like this

```
.
├── debianLaboration9
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── src
│       └── electrotest_standalone.c
└── debianLaboration9.tar.gz
```

and I don't know if is important but my makefile looks like this:

```
prefix = /usr/local
all: electrotest


electrotest: ./src/electrotest_standalone.c
    gcc -o electrotest_standalone ./src/electrotest_standalone.c -lm
install:electrotest
    sudo install -D electrotest_standalone \
    $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/electrotest_standalone
clean:
    -rm -f electrotest_standalone

distclean:clean
uninstall:
    sudo -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(prefix)/bin/electrotest_standalone

PHONY: all install clean distclean uninstall
```

To run debmake, I did

```
hoseopjeong@hoseopjeong-VirtualBox:~/Documents/HoseopJeong_debian_lab9$ cd debianLaboration9
hoseopjeong@hoseopjeong-VirtualBox:~/Documents/HoseopJeong_debian_lab9/debianLaboration9$ debmake
```

According to the site, debmake generates template files, but in my case debmake generates a FileNotFound error

```
I: set parameters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/debmake", line 28, in <module>
    debmake.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debmake/__init__.py", line 104, in main
    para = debmake.para.para(para)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debmake/para.py", line 44, in para
    debmail = os.getlogin() + '@localhost'
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can't understand why debmake generates a FileNotFound error...The version of debmake is 4.2.2-1

Answer (score 0):

Adding environment variable DEBEMAIL in ~/.bashrc solved the issue